# 18650 cells - Unable to measure capacity

Tags: discharge, battery-chemistry, lithium-ion

I got many 18650 batteries from notebook batteries and I want to test their capacity by my Turnigy Accucell 8.

My problem is, that when I start discharge program (0.5A what is from battery datasheet) it stops after 20mAh and battery have 2.75V. Battery recovers to 3.8V.

When I discharge slowly (0.1A) I get 1500-2000mAh what is right value.

Why this hapenning? How to discharge batteries faster? 0.1A is 10hours discharge time and I have 100 batteries to test...

Comment: Batteries have a double chemical layer effect in parallel that is like 2 caps a bigger one with a bigger ESR and a smaller one with lower ESR. The bigger one keeps the smaller one charged unless you discharge too fast.  I suggest Pulse charging over a float CV to restore some lower ESR.  THis is a natural aging effect from heat or really old  batteries  The weakest cell always dies 1st. Sort and match them.

Comment: Is there way how to recover them at least littlebit? Or they are just bad batteries what are not suitable for building scrap battery pack. I need to know if I connect them in pallarel of they have chance to explode or catch fire

Comment: I already told you.  Only match cells with same capacity on high current and try to restore with pulse charging  About a 10 million 1~10A pulses 1us

Comment: How did you charge the cells before starting your discharge test?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, have you personally ever successfully revived a battery using this pulse technique?

Comment: 10h is the discharge time used for mAh rating.  but if your cells only do 100mA for 10h that's only 1000mAh.

Comment: @Mkeith yes to many cell chemistries from solid to liquid . Here depends on thickness of cobalt dioxide crystalline growth that needs to broken down by piezo pulse resonance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that your cell samples are at the end of life and have developed substantial internal impedance. Apparently your tester is an intelligent one, and cuts off the discharge process at 2.75 V (or it could be the cut-off from internal cell protection, doesn't matter). When you set the current at 500 mA, the cell drops its output below the cut-off threshold, and the tester times off the capacity at very low value.

When you load your cells with 100 mA, the internal voltage drop is smaller, and cells last longer before the threshold is reached.

You need to perform a simple load test. First, measure the no-load voltage first, say V1. Then connect something like R=20-Ohm resistor. And quickly measure the resulting voltage, say V2. Your current is V2/R, and the internal impedance would be R * (V1-V2)/V2. If the result is more than 0.2-0.4 Ohms, your batteries are no good. It looks like in your case the internal cell impedance is about 2 Ohms (~1V drop from 500 mA load).

I am afraid your batch of batteries is bad, and you need to dispose them.

Comment: Do you suspect the low current capacity result ?

Comment: That theory seems inconsistent with the claimed 1500-2000 mAh measured at lower discharge, which isn't that much less than the likely *actual* (vs claimed) capacity of unbranded cells.

Comment: Yet my theory matches the result which indicate why it returns to 3.8V

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, my "theory" is that the cells could still have some capacity, just the impedance got out of whack, so the tester terminates prematurely. It is not unusual to have 50% - 60% capacity while discharge capability is severed by high internal impedance. I would guess that if OP lowers the cut-off limit from default  2.75V to 2.0-V-something or under, he would measure about the same capacity, 1500-2000 mAh. Note that the cell makes instant recovery, which is more consistent with my "impedance theory".

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt ... and discharge to external 2-V level won't hurt, since internally it is still well above the 2.5 V level (again due to internal impedance).

Comment: I measured 0.138Ohm resistance by your method on few cells charged to 3.7V

Comment: Bayern’s 138mohms compared to 20+/-50% new (my est. of 18650 ESR) [mOhms] is a ratio benchmark. But remember “double-layer effect capacitance”. So you can measure two time constants and thus 2 RC series pairs in parallel.  Short T =x  seconds,  Long T x minutes with a threshold above 2.5V

Comment: @Baterka, yes, 138 mOhms is about right. https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Common18650Summary%20UK.html  (scroll to the bottom) What about your questionable cells?